# How to fix this open cv library error working with dnn?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, yolo

I am using OpenCV dnn to load YOLO v3 weights and make predictions

error is coming from this line

```
    outs = self.net.forward(self.get_outputs_names(self.net))
```

[image]

this is whole error

Inference & prediction code

```
def get_outputs_names(self, net):
        layersNames = self.net.getLayerNames()
        return [layersNames[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]


def predict(self, image):
    blob = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1/255.0, (inpWidth, inpHeight), [0,0,0], 1, crop=False)
    self.net.setInput(blob)
    outs = self.net.forward(self.get_outputs_names(self.net))
    return outs


def infer_image(self, image):
    image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    outs = self.predict(image)
    return self.postprocess(image, outs)
```

what is causing this error?

Comment: What is the result of `self.get_output_names()`?

Comment: Thanks for reply,`['yolo_16', 'yolo_23']` this is the what `self.get_output_names()` is returning.